# run custom ROM files on Emulator

Tags: rom, android-emulator

I want to run ROM files of different phone models on Android emulator in my Windows PC.
Do you know how can i do so? I know how to run standard android emulators for INTEL and ARM however i want to run production ROM files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're willing to compile your own ROMs, you can definitely build them for the emulator. ROMs are device-specific, and the emulator is just like another device. If you include the drivers/setup code with the ROM, it will boot on the device.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that. As you already know, ROMs are built for the specific hardware they run on. They have drivers and settings that only work on that hardware. The emulator only emulates a particular hardware configuration, and requires its own drivers for the emulated hardware.

To run a ROM file for a phone you'd need to change the emulator to emulate the specific hardware of that phone. This is next to impossible without the support of the device manufacturer, and would need to be repeated for each device. Alternatively, if you had the source of the ROM, you could change it to have the drivers and configuration for the emulator, but then it wouldn't be the production ROM any more.

Comment: I want to do this to test apps in platform near to real production status. However, having sources, changing source code to run on emulator would be so tricky?

Comment: I don't know. Making ROMs for the emulator is outside my experience, and making custom ROMs is off-topic for this site like other development questions, because we're targeted at Android *users*.