# How to boot custom ROM on Android Emulator?

Tags: custom-roms, android-emulator, omnirom

I'm trying to run OmniROM on Android Emulator but I'm facing some problems.
Really, I'm able to build the nightlies (homemade) without problems and run the standard Android "vanilla" that comes with SDK, but I just don't know how to boot OmniROM on Android Emulator.

I created an avd with Nexus 5 configurations, I copied all img files in `out/target/product/hammerhead` to `~/.android/avd/hammerhead.avd/` but when I run the emulator all I get is a black screen (monitor shows device offline).

I also tried to run `make` in `~/android/omni` and then open emulator, same black screen and device offline.

Could someone point me the right direction?

Comment: [run custom ROM files on Emulator](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/54674) - Setting the emulator to use N5 specifications doesn't mean that it actually emulates it precisely. It just sets things like the screen size, resolution, and Android version to match that of the target. It's still emulating a different set of (generic) hardware, so the drivers and such for the N5 aren't going to work.

Comment: @eldarerathis So, what is the best way to test something you developed? Just building the ROM and flashing it?

Comment: Honestly, that might be the best way, but that's not really something I'm too familiar with. As long as you have a custom recovery (or fastboot) then your risk of bricking from a bad build should be pretty minimal, at least.